# Python loop to replace element by the difference with mean / variance of the series

Tags: python, for-loop

#python code to replace the value of each cell by mean and variance

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(2,5):
        df.iloc[i,j]=((df.iloc[i,j]-np.mean(df.iloc[i,2:]))/np.var(df.iloc[i,2:]))
```

My data is arranged in matrix format where j represent the observations and i represent the year as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['01/01/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/03/2019'], 
                   'descriptor':['BV','BV','BV'],
                   'abc': [0.8, 0.7, 0.6],
                  'bcd':[0.5,0.3,0.9],
                  'efg':[0.6,0.5,0.3]})
```

Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfD1c.png)

The correct output should be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KNTD.png)

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples, and include the relevant data in your question (as text) - both input and expected output.

Comment: Please post the question properly. I don't think people can understand what is the data and what expected output

Comment: #test_data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': ['01/01/2019', '01/02/2019', '01/03/2019'], 
                   'abc': [0.8, 0.7, 0.6],
                  'bcd':[0.5,0.3,0.9],
                  'efg':[0.6,0.5,0.3]})

Comment: @Rahul - please add the relevant data to the **question itself**. Also - please add the expected output.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you get from the input to the output? what calculation leads to 7.5, for example?

Comment: @Roy2012 , take the mean and variance of first row ( 0.8,,0.5,,0.6) and then substract from each value the mean and divide the result by variance so it should be like (0.8 - average(0.8,0.5,0.6))/variance (0.8,,0.5,,0.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
df.iloc[:,2:].subtract(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0).div(df.var(axis=1), axis=0)
```

The same calculation, in several steps for clarity:

```
relevant_columns = df.iloc[:,2:]

# Calculate mean and var per row (hence axis=1)
mean_per_row = df.mean(axis=1)
var_per_row = df.var(axis=1)

# subtract and then divide along the columns (hence axis=0)
val_minus_mean = relevant_columns.subtract(mean_per_row, axis=0)
res = val_minus_mean.div(var_per_row, axis=0)
```

Comment: yes this gives the correct result, can u explain the logic behind axis=0 for df.iloc[:,2:].subtract(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0) and then again axis =0 for df.iloc[:,2:].subtract(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0).div(df.var(axis=1), axis=0). Many thanks..

Comment: The additional notes in the answer.